# Accessing the instance from a ProvidedMethod

Tags: f#, type-providers

How do I access the (runtime) instance from the implementation of the a `ProvidedMethod`

that is if `foo` is of a provided type and the erased type is `Bar` with a method named `Execute`
Then given this code

```
foo.Execute()
```

I wish the `ProvidedMethod` to equal this

```
bar.Execute() //where bar is an object of type Bar
```

What I have is this

```
//p is a MethodInfo that represents Bar.Execute and m is the ProvidedMethod 
objm.InvokeCode <- fun args -> <@@ p.Invoke(--what goes here--,null) @@>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instance is passed as the first expression in the `args` array, so you can access it from there.

Also, the `InvokeCode` that you need to build should not capture the method info `p` and call `Invoke` on it using reflection. Instead, you need to build an F# quotation (akin to expression tree) that *represents* the invocation.

So, you need to write something like this:

```
objm.InvokeCode <- (fun args -> 
  // The 'args' parameter represents expressions that give us access to the 
  // instance on which the method is invoked and other parameters (if there are more)
  let instance = args.[0]
  // Now we can return quotation representing a call to MethodInfo 'p' with 'instance'
  Expr.Call(instance, p) )
```

Note that I did not use `<@@ .. @@>` here because you already have `MethodInfo` for the method that you want to call. If you instead wanted to call a method `ProviderRuntime.DoStuff(instance)` then you could use quotation literals:

```
objm.InvokeCode <- (fun args -> 
  let instance = args.[0]
  <@@ ProviderRuntime.DoStuff(%%instance) @@> )
```